# Convert from a binary to char in C

Tags: c, character-encoding, binary, char, type-conversion

I'm flummoxed by how to convert from a binary value to a char in c.

For example, let's say I have 01010110 and want to print the corresponding letter 'V' from that. How do I do this?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you mean you have "1010110"?  The binary number in a register, the 1/0 characters, what?  (If it's the binary value, a `(char)` cast is all you need.)

Comment: Show us code!!  Otherwise we are guessing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *data = "01010110";
    char c = strtol(data, 0, 2);
    printf("%s = %c = %d = 0x%.2X\n", data, c, c, c);
    return(0);
}
```

Output:

```
01010110 = V = 86 = 0x56
```

References:

- [`strtol()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html)
- [Correct usage of `strtol()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176123)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `strtol()` to parse a number on a string. The last argument (in this case 2) is the radix for the conversion.

```
char c = strtol("01010110", (char **)NULL, 2);
```

More information about this and other number parsing functions [here](http://h30097.www3.hp.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V51B_HTML/MAN/MAN3/1938____.HTM).

Answer (score -2):

Did something slightly different:

From the binary, I mathematically calculated the int and simply casted the int into a char.

```
int i;
char c = (char)i;
```

Comment: The final conversion is self-evident; the hand-waving 'from the binary, I mathematically calculated the int' contains no useful information.