# Convert string into number

Tags: c

I learned that numbers can be converted into strings with `sprintf`:

```
int main()
{
    int n; 
    char s[32];

    printf("n=");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    sprintf(s,"%d",n); //HERE
    puts(s);

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to convert a string into a number with a similar command, without checking if each character is a number?

Comment: `without checking if each character is a number` what do you mean by this? There are API's already as mentioned in the answers

Comment: @gopi: without using a `for` to check if s[i] is a number.

Comment: ok .. Yes there a bunch of answers for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`strtol`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) function.

```
long int strtol(const char * restrict nptr, char ** restrict endptr, int base);
```

The `strtol` convert the initial portion of the string pointed to by `nptr` to `long int` representation.

Better to not use `atoi`. It tells noting when unable to convert a string to integer unlike `strtol` which specify by using `endptr` that whether the conversion is successful or not. If no conversion could be performed, zero is returned.

Suggested reading: [correct usage of strtol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14176593/2455888)

Example:

```
char *end;
char *str = "test";
long int result = strtol(str, &end, 10);  

if (end == str || *temp != '\0')
    printf("Could not convert '%s' to long and leftover string is: '%s'\n", str, end);  
else 
    printf("Converted string is: %ld\n", result);
```

Comment: Sometimes  `atol` is also possible if you don't care for more than only the number in the string.

Comment: @harper; `atol` is equivalent to (int)strtol(nptr, (char **)NULL, 10)`

Comment: This expression is about 32 chars longer and makes the same? I think this is not fully equivalent. ;-) BTW: Don't cast a `void*` in `C`.

Comment: What is the second parameter used for? `char ** restrict endptr`

Comment: Can you give me an example for that `endptr` ?

Comment: @Abbey; Added an example.

Answer (score 3):

The `strtol` family of functions provide this capability. They allow you to convert a string to a numeric type (depending on which *member* of the family you choose) and, unlike the `atoi` family, also allow you to detect if scanning failed before reaching the end.

It does this by populating the pointer you pass with the address of the first character not included in the conversion. If this is anything other than the string terminator, it had to stop early.

There's also the special case where it may point at a terminator even when the string is invalid (specifically, the case of an empty string `""`).

As an example, the following program shows one way to use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i;
    long val;
    char *next;

    // Process each argument.

    for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        // Get value with failure detection.

        errno = 0;
        val = strtol (argv[i], &next, 10);

        // Check for empty string and characters left after conversion.

        if (errno == EINVAL) {
            printf ("'%s' invalid\n", argv[i]);
        } else if (errno == ERANGE) {
            printf ("'%s' out of range\n", argv[i]);
        } else if (next == argv[i]) {
            printf ("'%s' is not valid at first character\n", argv[i]);
        } else if (*next != '\0') {
            printf ("'%s' is not valid at subsequent character\n", argv[i]);
        } else {
            printf ("'%s' gives %ld\n", argv[i], val);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Running that code with the arguments `hi "" 42 3.14159 9999999999999999999999999 7 9q` gives:

```
'hi' is not valid at first character
'' is not valid at first character
'42' gives 42
'3.14159' is not valid at subsequent character
'9999999999999999999999999' out of range
'7' gives 7
'9q' is not valid at subsequent character
```

Answer (score 2):

> *"Is it possible to convert a string into a number with a similar command, without checking if each character is a number?"*

Yes, that's possible. [`atoi()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) was made for this purpose (see also the [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) function family in that reference).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `atoi` function.

```
 int atoi(const char *nptr);
```