# C Parse String Into Two Ints With Strtol

Tags: c, strtol

Assume I have a program that calculates the result of multiplying two integers together from a string. I use strtol to separate the first part but how do I separate the second int? For example, "12  5" would give a result of 60.

Right now my code looks like:

```
    int multiply(const char *input) {
        int result = 0;
        char *second_int;
        int i = strtol(input_line, &second_int, 10);

        result = i * second_int;

        return result;
```

So obviously right now this would give an error since I only converted the first part of the string to an integer. How do I convert the leftover string into an integer? Do I need another strtol line? Do I need to cast it? I'm unsure of how to go about this.

Comment: You need to invoke `strtol()` a second time, starting at the address returned by the first.  That assumes that both invocations will work.  Given `"12 15"`, it won't be a problem; given `"a b"`, it will.  You can test the result of `strtol()` and the pointer and `errno` (but you need to zero it before you call `strtol()`) to see whether the conversion worked.  See [Correct usage of `strtol()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176123/correct-usage-of-strtol) for the details.

Comment: Or a different tack with `if (sscanf(input, "%d%d", &i, &j) == 2) { result = i * j; }`

Answer (score 2):

`strtol` declaration is as following:

```
long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);
```

and from `man strtol`:

> If endptr is not NULL, strtol() stores the address of the first invalid character in *endptr.

So you can use the value stored in *endptr to start scanning for another value. Example:

```
char *str="12 5";
char *end;
printf("%ld\n", strtol(str, &end, 10));
printf("%ld\n", strtol(end, &end, 10));
```

will print:

```
12
5
```