# How to check if command line parameters are integers

Tags: c, parsing, command-line-arguments, c89

First of all, I am talking about old-fashioned ANSI-C (I mean the ANSI standard and no C99 or newer) compiled with gcc. I am only allowed to use the libraries that can be seen below in the code.

My problem is I have a program that is called in the following way on the Terminal:

```
program < integer_1 integer_2
```

While I have been able to figure out how to check for the number of arguments, I'm stuck on checking if those are integers.
If the program is called like this:

```
program < 1 -13
```

it should run without complaining but if it is run like this:

```
program < s 7
```

it should throw out an error.

Whatever I have tried so far has been utter rubbish. The best thing I have managed so far has been an error message if the second number has been a character. None of my tries has been able to deal with more than one digit but I have figured out why that is.

The problem is that I haven't used command line / terminal arguments with any programming language i now (C++, Java). I would really appreciate it if someone could show me how check for correct input as frankly I am out of ideas.

Am I correct that if I want to deal with numbers bigger than 9, I have to iterate through argv starting from index 2 until I find a space?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int arc, char *argv[])
{
  if(arc != 3)
  {
    printf("Error: You have entered %d arguments, but two were expected!", arc - 1);
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: All command line arguments are strings.  You can convert strings to integers using `atoi()` with no error checking, or using `strtol()` or one of its relatives with accurate and sensitive but very [delicate error checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176123/correct-usage-of-strtol).  Note that your command lines show an `<` which means that the shell tries to redirect standard input from a file with the name given by the next argument (`1` and `s` in the examples) and removes both the `<` and the file name from the command line.  You should simply delete the `<` symbol.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way out is to iterate over the `argv[n]`s and pass one by one to them to [`strtol()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) or similar. Then, check for the error and make the decision. To quote the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol), *(emphasis mine)*

> `long int strtol(const char *nptr, char **endptr, int base);`
>
> [...]
>
> If `endptr` is not `NULL`, `strtol()` stores the address of the first invalid character in `*endptr`. If there were no digits at all, `strtol()` stores the original value of `nptr` in `*endptr` (and returns 0). **In particular, if `*nptr` is not `'\0'` but `**endptr` is `'\0'` on return, the entire string is valid.**

That said, `program < integer_1 integer_2` is not exactly the way to pass the *command-line arguments*. If you want to pass the values arguments as command-line arguments, you shall lose the redirection operator and work with `argc` and `argv[n]`s directly..

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to create a function for checking whether it is number or not.if the below function returns true then use atoi(argv[]) to convert them to integers to use it further.

```
bool isNumber(char number[])
{
    int i = 0;

    //checking for negative numbers
    if (number[0] == '-')
        i = 1;
    for (; number[i] != 0; i++)
    {
        //if (number[i] > '9' || number[i] < '0')
        if (!isdigit(number[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this out. It works if I do something like that: program_name 7 g or program_name gh tz but it won't work if I enter first a char / string and then a number like this: program_name: yu 5. That was the point where I got stuck when I tried it on my own.

Comment: could you please share the exact test case ... bcz the code should work

Comment: The program isn't needed anymore. But I am still interested into figuring this stuff out. Therefore I will try to get a working solution this weekend which I will post. And sorry for the late reply. I am quite busy at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int check_cmd_args(char const *str[], int numargs);

int 
main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("Not enough command line arguements entered\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (check_cmd_args(argv, argc)) {
        printf("All Command line arguements are integers\n");
    } else {
        printf("Error, non-integer command line arguement entered\n");
    }

    return 0;
}

int
check_cmd_args(char const *str[], int numargs) {
    int n, i = 0;

    for (n = 1; n < numargs; n++) {
        if (str[n][0] == '-') {
            i = 1;
        }
        for (; str[n][i]; i++) {
            if (!isdigit(str[n][i])) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment: not an answer

If you are going to use

```
program < arg1 arg2
```

You will not see arg1 or arg2 in the main parameters.  arg1 is typically a filename or device which contain data which will be read by the program.  I don't know if the program will even be able to access arg2.  If you wish to pick up arg1 arg2 etc, lose the <

```
program arg1 arg2
```