# C Parsing String Function Argument Using strtol

Tags: c, parsing, strtol

I'm a bit new to C and want to understand a few things about accessing function arguments using pointers and dereferencing.

Here's my code, the whole point of the program is to use `strtol` to parse a given parameter with only two digits separated by whitespaces.

```
int sum(const char *input){
  char *input = input_line;   // dereference the address passed into the function to access the string
  int i; // store sum in here
  char *rest; // used as second argument in strtol so that first int can be added to i
  i = strtol(input, &rest, 10); // set first int in string to i
  i += strtol(rest, &rest, 10); // add first and second int
  return i;
}
```

I'm confused how to access the string parameter given because strings have a `*` by the variable name, and I'm not too sure how to work around that.

Anyway, thanks.

Comment: See [Correct usage of `strtol()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176123/correct-usage-of-strtol) for a fairly complete discussion on how to use `strtol()` properly.  Your current problems are more mundane, though.  Your code won't compile because you can't redefine a parameter (`input`) in the top-level of the body of the function.  You likely had in mind to name the parameter `input_line` and not `input`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to dereference the input parameter. If you simply drop the line

```
char *input = input_line;
```

(which isn't the right way to dereference it anyways), the code will work. You are passing `sum` a pointer to `char`, which is exactly what the first argument to `strol` should be.

A simple test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int sum(const char *input){
  int i; // store sum in here
  char *rest; // used as second argument in strtol so that first int can be added to i
  i = strtol(input, &rest, 10); // set first int in string to i
  i += strtol(rest, &rest, 10); // add first and second int
  return i;
}

int main(void){
    char* nums = "23 42";
    printf("%d\n",sum(nums)); 
    return 0;
}
```

It prints `65` as expected.

As far as the mechanics of dereferencing goes: If for some reason you really wanted to dereference the pointer passed to `sum` you would do something like this (inside `sum`):

```
char ch; // dereferencing a char* yields a char
ch = *input; // * is the dereference operator
```

Now `ch` would hold the first character in the input string. There is no reason at all to pass an individual `char` to `strol` hence such dereferencing is in this case pointless -- although there are of course valid reasons for sometimes in the body of a function dereferencing a pointer which is passed to that function.