# C read data as string and convert them to floats and write back in a file

Tags: c, string, split

I want to read in a dataset with numbers in strings like:
(in this example each number has 3 digits: 128, 6, -3 and 224)

```
128  6 -3224
```

and write them into floats like:

```
nbr[0] = 128;
nbr[1] = 6;
nbr[2] = -3;
nbr[3] = 224;
```

then calculate something (e.g. times 2) and write them in another file of the same type:

```
256 12 -6448
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Is the first number `123` or `128`? Why do you merge the last two numbers? What have you tried, and what is the question?

Comment: `-1555` ==> `-21110` ?

Comment: Why do you say "each number has 3 digits" and then post numbers with 3, 1 and 4 digits?

Comment: The first number is 128 not 123 (a mistake).

Comment: The first number is 128 not 123 (a mistake). All numbers have 3 digits, also counting whitespaces: 128,__6,_-3,224. They are written in a string as a combination of chars. In Fortran this is a simple task, just read in the complete line, split them into substrings each 3 digits long and the convert them to floats. In C i read in the line with: fgets with a string for each line but dont know how to split this string into substrings. here is another example for a line: string:127625141 into floats:127, 625, 141

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow,  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages, but more urgently, please read about creating an MCVE ([MCVE]).  [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  Why floats?  The numbers shown are all integers and handling integers is easier.  And … oh, you've updated the question a bit.  So, each number occupies three places (has a width of 3), hence `" -3"` (3 places) and `"224"` (also 3 places).  So, `scanf("%3d", &integer_var)` would work, along with `printf("%3d", integer_var);`.

Comment: You should probably also read [Using `sscanf()` in loops](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975236/how-to-use-sscanf-in-loops).

Answer (score 0):

Using `scanf()` or its relatives is hard; *very* hard.

All the conversion specifiers except `%c`, `%[…]` (scan sets) and `%n` skip leading white space.  That makes it hard to apply a numeric conversion for a fixed width.

All the code below tacitly assumes that there are no more than 20 numbers on the line — it doesn't check bounds to ensure that (but operational code most certainly should — or could use dynamic memory allocation to allocate more space for numbers when needed).

### Bogus code — looks simple, but fails

```
/* SO 4564-1845 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[4096];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
    {
        int nbr[20];
        int num = 0;
        int n;
        int val;
        int off = 0;
        while (sscanf(line + off, "%3d%n", &val, &n) == 1)
        {
            printf("Got: %d - [%s] %d\n", val, line + off, n);
            off += n;
            nbr[num++] = val;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            printf("%3d", nbr[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

#### Example output

This program was called `rd31`.  Note there is debug output here too:

```
$ rd31 < data
Got: 128 - [128  6 -3224
] 3
Got: 6 - [  6 -3224
] 3
Got: -32 - [ -3224
] 4
Got: 24 - [24
] 2
128  6-32 24
$
```

The `%3d` format skips the leading blank in `" -3"` and takes the `2` of `224` as the third character.  This isn't what you want.

### Working code — more complex, but passes

This code keeps using `sscanf()`, invoking it twice per number, which may be sub-optimal.

```
/* SO 4564-1845 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[4096];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
    {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        int nbr[20];
        int num = 0;
        int n;
        int val;
        char data[4];
        int off = 0;
        while (sscanf(line + off, "%3c%n", data, &n) == 1)
        {
            data[n] = '\0';
            if (sscanf(data, "%d", &val) != 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Oops! [%s]\n", data);
                break;
            }
            printf("Got: [%s] - [%s] = %d (%d)\n", data, line + off, val, n);
            off += n;
            nbr[num++] = val;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            printf("%3d", nbr[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This has different diagnostic output.  It reads the data into a string, and then converts the string.  Using `data[n] = '\0';` nulls the end of what was read.

#### Example output

This program was called `rd53`.

```
$ rd53 < data
Got: [128] - [128  6 -3224] = 128 (3)
Got: [  6] - [  6 -3224] = 6 (3)
Got: [ -3] - [ -3224] = -3 (3)
Got: [224] - [224] = 224 (3)
128  6 -3224
$
```

This is what you want, I believe.

### Alternative code — using `sscanf()` just once per value

This code uses `memmove()` to copy data from the line into a buffer for conversion.

```
/* SO 4564-1845 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char line[4096];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin) != 0)
    {
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        int nbr[20];
        int num = 0;
        int val;
        char data[4];
        int off = 0;
        int len = strlen(line);
        while (off < len)
        {
            memmove(data, line + off, 3);
            data[3] = '\0';
            if (sscanf(data, "%d", &val) != 1)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Oops! [%s]\n", data);
                break;
            }
            printf("Got: [%s] - [%s] = %d\n", data, line + off, val);
            off += 3;
            nbr[num++] = val;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            printf("%3d", nbr[i]);
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You could also use `atoi()` or `strtol()` to convert the string to a number.  Overflow isn't an issue with at most 3 digits to convert.  Still, non-numeric data would cause some minor issues; you can protect against them better if you use `strtol()`, but doing so requires considerable care.  (See [Correct usage of `strtol()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176123) for more details.)

#### Example output

This program was called `rd89`.

```
$ rd89 < data
Got: [128] - [128  6 -3224] = 128
Got: [  6] - [  6 -3224] = 6
Got: [ -3] - [ -3224] = -3
Got: [224] - [224] = 224
128  6 -3224
$
```