# Reading a CSV file in C using fgets and strtok only reads first column

Tags: c, io, strtok

I have a .csv file that looks like

```
Config,Prob,MAN,ATL,CVERT,TVERT,LVERT,PELV,SAC,RIB,SCAP,PHUM,DHUM,PRAD,DRAD,CARP,PMC,DMC,PHX,PFEM,DFEM,PTIB,DTIB,TARS,PMT,DMT
LH,1,2,2,7,13,6,2,1,13,2,2,2,1,1,6,2,2,24,2,2,2,2,8,2,2
LH,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9,1,2,2,2,2,12,2,2,18,1,1,1,1,4,1,1
LH,1,2,2,7,3,0,2,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,6,1,1,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
LH,1,0,0,0,13,6,2,1,8,0,2,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
LH,1,2,2,4,13,6,2,1,18,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
LH,1,0,0,0,13,6,2,1,18,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,0,0
LH,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
LH,1,0,0,0,13,6,2,1,24,2,2,2,2,2,12,2,2,24,2,2,2,2,8,2,2
LH,1,0,0,1,13,3,2,1,15,2,0,0,2,2,0,0,0,6,2,2,2,2,0,0,0
LH,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,10,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,18,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
LH,1,0,2,7,3,0,0,0,7,2,2,2,2,2,12,2,2,24,2,2,2,2,8,2,2
LH,1,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,14,1,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,18,2,2,2,2,0,0,0
LK,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,13,0,0,0,1,1,6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
LK,1,2,2,7,13,6,2,1,17,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,6,1,1,1,1,4,1,1
LK,1,0,0,0,10,6,0,0,23,1,1,1,1,1,6,1,1,18,2,2,2,2,8,2,2
LK,1,2,2,7,0,0,0,0,18,2,0,0,1,1,12,2,2,24,2,2,2,2,8,2,2
LK,1,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,2,2,12,2,2,24,2,2,2,2,8,2,2
LK,1,2,2,7,0,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,2,2,12,2,2,24,0,0,2,2,8,2,2
LK,3,2,2,7,13,6,2,1,22,2,2,2,2,2,12,2,2,24,2,2,2,2,8,2,2
LK,1,2,2,7,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
LK,1,2,2,6,0,3,0,0,11,0,2,2,0,0,12,2,2,18,0,0,0,0,8,2,2
LK,1,2,2,7,13,6,2,1,16,2,1,1,2,2,12,2,2,6,2,2,2,2,8,2,2
LK,1,2,0,0,10,6,2,1,19,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
LK,1,2,2,5,13,6,2,1,12,1,0,0,0,0,12,2,2,6,0,0,0,0,8,2,2
```

I would like to ignore the text and just grab the numbers. Here is my code:

```
    int arr[rows][columns]; /* rows/columns of .csv file */
    char buf[1000];
    int r = 0;

    while (fgets(buf,1000,ifp)) {
        char read = 'N';
        const char *tok;
        int ret =0;
        int c = 0;
        int count = 0;
        char *ptr;
        printf("%s \n", buf);

        for (tok = strtok(buf, ","); tok && *tok; tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n")){
                printf("%s ", buf); /* replace buf with tok */
                if(isNumber(tok)==1){
                    read = 'Y';
                    ret = strtol(tok,&ptr,10);
                    arr[r][c] = ret;
                    c++;
                    printf("Entered ");
                    //printf("%ld ", arr[r][c]);
                }
                if(strtok(NULL,"\n") && read == 'N')
                    count++;
        }
        r++;
        //r -= count;
    }
```

`isNumber` is essentially an extension of `isdigt` and works as intended. However, whenever printing out `tok` for each iteration, it stops after the first comma. Sample output: `Config LH LH LH LH LH LH LH LH LH LH LH LH LK LK LK LK LK LK LK LK LK LK LK LK`. It seems to be reading the input just fine using `fgets`, as it prints out each line of the .csv file. So it seems like the issue lies with my for loop. It seems that I am incrementing my token incorrectly.

Attempting with another example:

```
    char alph[] = "a-b-c-e";
    for (const char *tok = strtok(alph, "-"); tok && *tok; tok = strtok(NULL, "-\0")){
        printf("%s ", tok);
    }
```

yields:
`a b c e`, which is the correct result.
Therefore, I feel like I am missing something here with parsing my file. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is:

```
 for (tok = strtok(buf, ","); tok && *tok; tok = strtok(NULL, ",\n")) 
 {
     …omitted…
     if (strtok(NULL, "\n") && read == 'N')
         count++;
 }
```

You have three calls to `strtok()`, and the one in the `if` eats up everything to the newline.  I'm not sure what you were thinking there.  It looks like you should omit that `strtok()` — but I'm not sure what you need to replace it with.

Because the second call in the loop control reads up to newline or comma (`strtok(NULL, ",\n")`), you can't tell when you reach the end of the line except that `tok` is set to `NULL` to indicate no more tokens.

Comment: This fixed it, thank you. I was attempting to check to see if `tok` was at the end of the line, but I got a little crazy with using `strtotk`.

Comment: Note that if a line came in with a single number, you'd get the newline included in the token from the `tok = strtok(buf, ",")` call to `strtok()`.  Your call to `strtol()` would cheerfully ignore it, though, so there'd be no harm done.  If you're not going to use the value that `strtol()` stores in `ptr`, you could pass `NULL` instead of `&ptr` and then eliminate the unused variable.  Or you can validate that the number was really read — but doing that is surprisingly tricky (see [Correct usage of `strtol()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14176123) for most of the sordid details).