# How to determine whether a given argument is an integer or not

Tags: c

I need to read args given by the user. They would type something like `./main -3 word1 word2 word3...` and so forth.

I need a way to parse the first argument given to determine if it's an integer or not. If it is then I need to snag that integer. Here is the code I have worked up thus far.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int b, char** locations) {

    char determine = locations[1];
    return 0;
}
```

As far as I understand `strtok()` picks apart a string by an argument you give it. For example you can remove the space from a string that you know contains a string.

The problem is that in my situation the user can either enter a number or enter no number and I need to differentiate whether the first argument given is an integer or not. If it is then I need to be able to obtain the integer as a variable.

One thing that helps me though is that if the user is going to enter an integer then they have to use a `-` in front of it.

Comment: I don't believe so, the first argument can either be a string or string integer combo, so either its a string like "someString like this" or if the user gives an integer they have to use the "-" in front of the integer for example "-(somenumber)"

Comment: This is not correct statement anyway `char determine = locations[1];`

Comment: Command line args are given to you as seperate strings. So `./main -3 word1 word2` gives you strings in `locations[1]`, `locations[2]` and `locations[3]`. Then you can use the info in the linked post to check `locations[1]` which in the example will contain exactly `-3`.

Comment: You can use[`strtol()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html) (carefully) to do most of the work of finding out whether the string is an integer or not.  You might need to check whether there are non-digits after it stops converting, but that's all.  (See also [Correct usage of `strtol()`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14176123/15168) for more information.)

Comment: Note that it is conventional to call the arguments to `main()` by the names `argc` and `argv` — though some people use `ac` and `av`.  Your code will be more readily recognizable if you use the standard names.  It isn't formally wrong to use other names, but …  You should check that `b > 1` before using `locations[1]` — using your nomenclature.

Comment: So first you'd determine if the **first** character in an argument is `'-'`? Right? After that it is correct usage of `strtol` from *2nd character* onwards

Comment: i appreciate your advice, i am only a junior in university at the moment so that will be helpful to know later on when i work for the industry