# Does strtoull always return a valid number or set errno?

Tags: c, error-handling, language-lawyer, strtoull

Is `strtoull` guaranteed to either return a valid number, or set `errno` (if no valid number could be parsed)?

In other words, is this

```
errno = 0;
n = strtoull(s, 0, 10);
if (errno) {
  perror(s);
  exit(1);
}
// do something with n
```

correct, or is some other check also required?

Comment: Beware: the C standard doesn't say that `errno` shall be set if no conversion can be performed — see C11 [§7.22.1.4 The `strtol`, `strtoll`, `strtoul` and `strtoull` functions](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.1.4). It is likely that implementations do set `errno` then, but it's not mandatory according to the C standard. (As I type, the question is tagged both C and C++.). I've not checked the C++ standard today to see whether that is true there too. See also [Correct usage of `strtol`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14176123/15168l). According to the standard, more checks are needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.  The C standard (§7.22.1.7 of at least drafts N1570 through N2454, so C11 through C18) only mentions setting `errno` in one place:

> If the correct value is outside the range of representable values, `LONG_MIN`, `LONG_MAX`, `LLONG_MIN`, `LLONG_MAX`, `ULONG_MAX`, or `ULLONG_MAX` is returned (according to the return type and sign of the value, if any), and the value of the macro `ERANGE` is stored in `errno`.

There is another possible error condition, however.  “If no conversion could be performed, zero is returned,” and “the value of `nptr` is stored in the object pointed to by `endptr`, provided that `endptr` is not a null pointer.”  Otherwise, a pointer to “the final string” would be stored there, which would compare greater to `nptr`.

Therefore, a truly standard-compliant C program should check both conditions.  This test program, compiled with `clang -std=c18` on Windows 10:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
  const char s[] = "a1";

  errno = 0;
  char* unparsed = NULL;
  const unsigned long long int n =
    strtoull( s, &unparsed, 10 );
  
  if ( errno || (!n && s == unparsed) ) {
    fflush(stdout); // Don't cross the streams!
    perror(s);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  
  printf( "%llu\n", n );
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

produces the output `a1: No error`, so on this implementation, `errno` is not set.

As chqrlie brings up in the comments, it would have sufficed to check `( errno || s == unparsed )`.  If neither of these conditions hold, there was a conversion performed on a non-empty subject sequence.

Comment: Checking the value of `n` seems redundant. If a number was found, `unparsed` will be `> s` to it suffices to write: `if ( errno || s == unparsed )`