# list convertion in C

Tags: c

I am trying to make put command line arguments by the user into an array but I am unsure how to approach it.

For example say I ran my program like this.

./program 1,2,3,4,5

How would I store 1 2 3 4 5 without the commas, and allow it to be passed to other functions to be used. I'm sure this has to do with using argv.

PS: NO space-separated, I want the numbers to parse into integers, I have an array of 200, and I want these numbers to be stored in the array as, arr[0] = 1, arr[1] = 2....

store 1 2 3 4 5 without the commas, and allow it to be passed to other functions to be used.

Comment: Why insist on the commas? The solution does involve `argc` and `argv` (assuming you write `int main(int argc, char **argv)` or equivalent). Do you want the numbers to be parsed into strings or integers? Things would be much clearer if you showed some code — the function you want to call and also your best effort so far.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses) or an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — the same idea by a different name.

Comment: I want the numbers to parse into integers

Comment: OK; so which functions allow you to parse strings into integers?  There are a plethora of them to choose from.  What have you tried?  How will you decide how big the array of integers should be?  Will you use dynamic memory allocation (`malloc()` etc), or have you not covered that yet?  These sorts of questions are why we like to see what you've tried — they help us calibrate our answers so that they'll help you rather than bewilder you.

Comment: I have an array of 200, and I want these numbers to be stored in the array as, arr[0] = 1....

Comment: The generally accepted approach would be to loop with `strtol()` setting `nptr = argv[1]` and using `endptr` to update and have point to the `','` following each successful conversion (or to the nul-terminating character after the last integer). [man 3 strtol](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) is your friend. (yes, man-pages are a bit cryptic at first, but if you make friends with them you learn they provide you with concise information about the use of the function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> PS: NO space-separated, I want the numbers to parse into integers

Space or comma-separated doesn't matter. Arguments always come in as strings. You will have to do the work to turn them into integers using [`atoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/atoi) (Ascii-TO-Integer).

Using spaces between arguments is the normal convention: `./program 1 2 3 4 5`. They come in already separated in `argv`.
Loop through `argv` (skipping argv[0], the program name) and run them through `atoi`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
        int num = atoi(argv[i]);
        printf("%d: %d\n", i, num);
    }
}
```

Using commas is going to make that harder. You first have to split the string using the kind of weird [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) (STRing TOKenizer). Then again call `atoi` on the resulting values.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *token = strtok(argv[1], ",");
    while(token) {
        int num = atoi(token);
        printf("%d\n", num);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
    }
}
```

This approach is also more fragile than taking them as individual arguments. If the user types `./program 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` only `1` will be read.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin No, because they're no longer in `argv[1]`. You have to do both: `strtok` on each element of `argv`.

Comment: Uugh -- you are right. Hope springs eternal. There space does present a sticky-wicket.

Comment: Beware that strtok() modifies the array it is passed. Not guaranteed safe on argv[]. Might need to strdup() first (and then free).

Comment: Er, apparently the strings in `argv[]` _are_ modifiable, as per [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function).

Comment: It seems to create a segmentation fault when I replace the int num with an array

Comment: @work It's only a guess, but did you allocate the array? Something like `int nums[argc-1]`?

Comment: I did have something like int nums[size]

Comment: @work To help, I'll need to see what you tried.

Comment: Hi, I did this "while(token) {
for (int i = 0; i < argc -1; i++) {
        int num = atoi(token);
        arr[i] = num;
        printf("%d\n", arr[i]);
        token = strtok(NULL, ",");
}
    }" but when I tried to print the array outside the while loop, it prints wrong values

Comment: @work [Look at this](https://www.online-cpp.com/kXGbiARxuM). With `./program 1,2,3,4` `argc` will always be 2. `i` will only ever be 0 so you're setting `arr[0]` over and over again. Instead, you need to increment `i` as you're looping over the tokens [like this](https://www.online-cpp.com/EsQa3CyvGR). Like I said in the answer, you're doing it the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd deal with your requirement using [`strtol()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtol.html).  This does not damage the input string, unlike solutions using `strtok()`.  It also handles overflows and underflows correctly, unlike solutions using `atoi()` or its relatives.  The code assumes you want to store an array of type `long`; if you want to use `int`, you can add testing to see if the value converted is larger than `INT_MAX` or less than `INT_MIN` and report an appropriate error if it is not a valid `int` value.

Note that handling errors from `strtol()` is a tricky business, not least because every return value (from `LONG_MIN` up to `LONG_MAX`) is also a valid result.  See also [Correct usage of strtol()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14176123/15168).  This code requires no spaces before the comma; it permits them after the comma (so you could run `./csa43 '1, 2, -3, 4,     5'` and it would work). It does not allow spaces before commas.  It allows leading spaces, but not trailing spaces.  These issues could be fixed with more work — probably mostly in the `read_value()` function.  It may be that the validation work in the main loop should be delegated to the `read_value()` function — it would give a better separation of duty.  OTOH, what's here works within limits.  It would be feasible to allow trailing spaces, or spaces before commas, if that's what you choose.  It would be equally feasible to prohibit leading spaces and spaces after commas, if that's what you choose.

```c
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int read_val(const char *str, char **eov, long *value)
{
    errno = 0;
    char *eon;
    if (*str == '\0')
        return -1;
    long val = strtol(str, &eon, 0);

    if (eon == str || (*eon != '\0' && *eon != ',') ||
        ((val == LONG_MIN || val == LONG_MAX) && errno == ERANGE))
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not convert '%s' to an integer "
                "(the leftover string is '%s')\n", str, eon);
        return -1;
        }
    *value = val;
    *eov = eon;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s n1,n2,n3,...\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    enum { NUM_ARRAY = 200 };
    long array[NUM_ARRAY];
    size_t nvals = 0;

    char *str = argv[1];
    char *eon;
    long  val;
    while (read_val(str, &eon, &val) == 0 && nvals < NUM_ARRAY)
    {
        array[nvals++] = val;
        str = eon;
        if (str[0] == ',' && str[1] == '\0')
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: trailing comma in number string\n", argv[1]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (str[0] == ',')
            str++;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nvals; i++)
        printf("[%zu] = %ld\n", i, array[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output (program `csa43` compiled from `csa43.c`):

```
$ csa43 1,2,3,4,5
[0] = 1
[1] = 2
[2] = 3
[3] = 4
[4] = 5
$
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the main disadvantages to using `atoi()` is it provides no check on the string it is processing and will happily accept `atoi ("my-cow");` and silently fail returning `0` without any indication of a problem. While a bit more involved, using `strtol()` allows you to determine what failed, and then recover. This can be as simple or as in-depth a recovery as your design calls for.

As mentioned in the comment, `strtol()` was designed to work through a string, converting sets of digits found in the string to a numeric value. On each call it will update the `endptr` parameter to point to the next character in the string after the last digit converted (to each `','` in your case -- or the nul-terminating character at the end). [man 3 strtol](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) provides the details.

Since `strtol()` updates `endptr` to the character after the last digit converted, you check if `nptr == endptr` to catch the error when no digits were converted. You check `errno` for a numeric conversion error such as overflow. Lastly, since the return type is `long` you need to check if the value returned is within the range of an `int` before assigning to your `int` array.

Putting it altogether with a very minimal bit of error handling, you could do something like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define NELEM 200   /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
  
  int arr[NELEM] = {0}, ndx = 0;            /* array and index */
  char *nptr = argv[1], *endptr = nptr;     /* nptr and endptr */
  
  if (argc < 2) {       /* if no argument, handle error */
    fputs ("error: no argument provided.\n", stderr);
    return 1;
  }
  else if (argc > 2) {  /* warn on more than 2 arguments */
    fputs ("warning: more than one argument provided.\n", stdout);
  }
  
  while (ndx < NELEM) {     /* loop until all ints processed or arr full */
    int error = 0;          /* flag indicating error occured */
    long tmp = 0;           /* temp var to hold strtol return */
    char *onerr = NULL;     /* pointer to next comma after error */
    errno = 0;              /* reset errno */
    
    tmp = strtol (nptr, &endptr, 0);      /* attempt conversion to long */
    
    if (nptr == endptr) {   /* no digits converted */
      fputs ("error: no digits converted.\n", stderr);
      error = 1;
      onerr = strchr (endptr, ',');
    }
    else if (errno) {       /* overflow in conversion */
      perror ("strtol conversion error");
      error = 1;
      onerr = strchr (endptr, ',');
    }
    else if (tmp < INT_MIN || INT_MAX < tmp) {  /* check in range of int */
      fputs ("error: value outside range of int.\n", stderr);
      error = 1;
      onerr = strchr (endptr, ',');
    }
    
    if (!error) {           /* error flag not set */
      arr[ndx++] = tmp;     /* assign integer to arr, advance index */
    }
    else if (onerr) {       /* found next ',' update endptr to next ',' */
      endptr = onerr;
    }
    else {                  /* no next ',' after error, break */
      break;
    }
    
    /* if at end of string - done, break loop */
    if (!*endptr) {
      break;
    }
    
    nptr = endptr + 1;      /* update nptr to 1-past ',' */
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < ndx; i++) {   /* output array content */
    printf (" %d", arr[i]);
  }
  putchar ('\n');           /* tidy up with newline */
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

This will handle your normal case, e.g.

```
$ ./bin/argv1csvints 1,2,3,4,5
 1 2 3 4 5
```

It will warn on bad arguments in list while saving all good arguments in your array:

```
$ ./bin/argv1csvints 1,my-cow,3,my-cat,5
error: no digits converted.
error: no digits converted.
 1 3 5
```

As well as handling completely bad input:

```
$ ./bin/argv1csvints my-cow
error: no digits converted.
```

Or no argument at all:

```
$ ./bin/argv1csvints
error: no argument provided.
```

Or more than the expected 1 argument:

```
$ ./bin/argv1csvints 1,2,3,4,5 6,7,8
warning: more than one argument provided.
 1 2 3 4 5
```

The point to be made it that with a little extra code, you can make your argument parsing routine as robust as need be. While your use of a single argument with comma-separated values is unusual, it is doable. Either manually tokenizing (splitting) the number on the commas with `strtok()` (or `strchr()` or combination of `strspn()` and `strcspn()`), looping with `sscanf()` using something similar to the `"%d%n"` format string to get a minimal succeed / fail indication with the offset of the next number from the last, or using `strtol()` and taking advantage of its error reporting. It's up to you.

Look things over and let me know if you have questions.