# Writing a Program that expects an integer input and returns an error for other data types

Tags: c, scanf

I was trying to write a code that returns an error for getting an input other than an integer data type.

```
void error() {
    printf("Invalid Input. Please Try Again.");
    exit(0); //terminate program after invalid input
}

int main() {
    
    int myHW, myQ, myME, myFE, myGrade; //score variables
    
    printf("Grade Calculation Program\n***************************\n\n"); //header

    printf("Please enter your scores.\n");
    
    printf("Homework Score (out of 20): "); //homework score
    ( scanf("%d", &myHW) == 1) ? : error(); 
    (myHW>=0 && myHW<=20) ? : error(); 
    
    
    printf("Quiz Score (out of 30): "); //quiz score
    ( scanf("%d", &myQ) == 1) ? : error();
    (myQ>=0 && myQ<=30) ? : error(); 
    
    printf("Midterm Exam Score (out of 20): "); //midterm exam score
    ( scanf("%d", &myME) == 1) ? : error();
    (myME>=0 && myME<=20) ? : error(); 
    
    printf("Final Exam Score (out of 30): "); //final exam score
    ( scanf("%d", &myFE) == 1) ? : error();
    (myFE>=0 && myFE<=30) ? : error();
```

I tried using

`( scanf("%d", &myHW) == 1) ? : error();`

but the program only returns the error if the user input's first character is a char/letter to begin with (a, f25, bd236.5 are some of the inputs i've tried) or if the integer before the char/decimal is already out of bounds (e.g. 25a, 28bd,29.5). if i try an input of a float/double data type or a combination of an integer that is still within the bounds of the parameter followed by a char (e.g. 12.5, 5.3, 5a), the program jumps to the next line first before delivering the error.

> Please enter your scores.
> Homework Score (out of 20): 5a
> Quiz Score (out of 30): Invalid Input. Please Try Again.

this is an instance of the said error.

I know it has something to do with me using the return value of scanf in the conditional. from what i've seen scanf returns 1 as long as the input begins with a number. i'm fairly new to programming and i just wanted to try messing with some of the problems that our prof has given but i can't seem to come up with a solution for this one

Comment: Use `fgets()` for user input.

Comment: Add a %s after the %d so you capture something that comes after the number. If scanf returns 0 or 2, then you found an error.

Comment: Note that this is not standard C: `(scanf("%d", &myHW) == 1) ?: error();` and it also is awful to read. Make it `if(scanf("%d", &myHW) != 1) error();`.

Comment: When `scanf()` is trying to read a number, it succeeds if the beginning of the input is a number. It stops reading after the number, leaving the rest available for the next call, which might not be looking for a number.

Comment: There is a wonderful refactoring opportunity that will make the code a lot easier to read.

Comment: After `fgets()`, use `strtol()` for conversion. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14176593/20017547

Comment: @Chlaus `printf("Invalid Input. Please Try Again."); exit(0);` is confusing.  On error do you intend to try again input or exit?  The choice impacts how to read an integer in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

In trying out your code I saw some areas where the user experience could be enhanced, standard character and digit functionality could be used, and some redundancies that could be consolidate.  As a result, following is a refactored version of your code that should make the user experience more fluid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void error()
{
    printf("Invalid Input. Please Try Again.\n");
    return;
}

int allDigits(char *word)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        if ((word[i] == '\0') || (word[i] == 10))   /* Reached the terminator or newline character  */
            return 1;
        if (isdigit(word[i]) == 0)                  /* Standard ctype.h function                    */
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int getInput(char *input_type, int max)
{
    char inp[10];
    int result;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("%s", input_type);
        if (fgets(inp, 4, stdin) == NULL)
        {
            error();
            continue;
        }
        if (allDigits(inp) == 0)
        {
            error();
            continue;
        }
        result = atoi(inp);
        if (result < 0 || result > max)
        {
            error();
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    int myHW, myQ, myME, myFE, myGrade;         //score variables

    printf("Grade Calculation Program\n***************************\n\n"); //header

    printf("Please enter your scores.\n");

    myHW = getInput("Homework Score (out of 20)....: ", 20);    /* Homework score       */
    myQ  = getInput("Quiz Score (out of 30)........: ", 30);    /* Quiz score           */
    myME = getInput("Midterm Exam Score (out of 20): ", 20);    /* Midterm exam         */
    myFE = getInput("Final Exam Score (out of 30)..: ", 30);    /* Final exam           */

    myGrade = myHW + myQ + myME + myFE;

    printf("Recap:\nHomework....: %d\nQuiz........: %d\nMidterm Exam: %d\nFinal Exam..: %d\n- - - - - - - - -\nTotal Score.: %d\n", myHW, myQ, myME, myFE, myGrade);

    return 0;
}
```

Some key bits to point out in this refactored code.

- The "string.h" and "ctype.h" include files were added to allow for the usage of standard character and digit checking along with standard conversions of string data to integer data.
- Noting in the good comments that telling the user that some type of input error had happened and then exiting the program seemed to make the user experience a bit murky, so the exiting was changed to a return to allow the user to retry the entry.
- Also noting in the good comments that the "fgets()" function was probably a better choice for user input, that was changed in the refactored code.
- Noticing a lot of redundant function calls and input validation led to pulling that redundant code out of the main function and wrapping it up in a general purpose function that can be reused for each category of input (e.g. homework, quiz, midterm exam, and final exam), thus reducing the size of the program.
- Making an educated guess, the code was completed to calculate a total score and print the student's statistics.

With those bits of refactoring, following is sample output for a student.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/Scores/bin/Release$ ./Scores 
Grade Calculation Program
***************************

Please enter your scores.
Homework Score (out of 20)....: 17
Quiz Score (out of 30)........: 25
Midterm Exam Score (out of 20): 13
Final Exam Score (out of 30)..: 28
Recap:
Homework....: 17
Quiz........: 25
Midterm Exam: 13
Final Exam..: 28
- - - - - - - - -
Total Score.: 83
```

Review this refactored code and use it as food for thought.  And always be on the lookout where code can be refactored when similar or identical functionality is being repeated.  It's usually a signal that the repeated steps can be encapsulated within a function that then can be called multiple times with different input parameters.  And as always, always reference available coding tutorials on the use of standard functions within the language to avoid needlessly recreating existing functionality.

Comment: I think the behavior of taking an empty input line as a zero doesn't make the user experience smooth, especially after a 3-digit-number has been entered.

Comment: Thank you for the refactored code as well as the pieces of advice! Most of the syntax used here aren't covered by our lectures yet but I took the time to study each function and follow the flow of the algorithm to the best of my ability.
My current prof accepted my initial code as we were still on the subject of If... Else... statements. Though it wasn't required for the problem, I wanted to provide some sort of error handling algorithm. I don't have a lot of knowledge with programming yet so my previous output was the best I could come up with.