# how can i convert binary to string in c

Tags: c, string, binary

I want to create a function that converts a binary (int type) to string. 
for example : if i have this 
01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00100000 01010111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100

the function should return "Hello World".

Comment: This really smells like homework. Please add your own attempts. If you got any concrete problems we will be happy to help you.

Comment: In which part of int are value? What have you tried so far? Show us some efforts and we will help you...

Comment: This is not the site for getting your home work done !

Comment: @Feathercrown It isn't a duplicate. OP said _function that converts a binary **(int type)** to string_

Comment: @LPs Ah, good catch. I've retracted my flag.

Comment: learn about bitwise operations (particularly setting bits `OR` and shifting) they will help

Answer (score 3):

Basicly you must convert the binary code in decimal number (see the table at http://www.asciitable.com/ ). E.g. - 01001000 = 72 (ASCII -> H), 01100101 = 101 (ASCII -> e), etc... Conversion between binary and decimal is very simple: 
**01001000** = 
(0 * 10^7) + (1* 10^6) + (0 * 10^5) + (0 * 10^4) + (1 * 10^3) + (0 * 10^2) + (0 * 10^1) + (0 * 10^0) = 
0 + 64 + 0 + 0 + 8 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 72 (in ASCII code = H)

Comment: OP's states input is a _string_.

Answer (score 0):

I think strtol is the way you should go.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtol.htm

Break your letters in peaces o 8 to get individual chars.

Here you got an example:
[Convert from a binary to char in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825218/convert-from-a-binary-to-char-in-c)

Edit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *data = "01010110";
    char c = strtol(data, 0, 2);
    printf("%s = %c = %d = 0x%.2X\n", data, c, c, c);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: In other approach you can convert from bin to int and use char c = (char) int_val;

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15728456)

Comment: Gotit. I will edit the answer.