# Converting char to binary strings and vice-versa

Tags: c

I need to store an 8-bit string into a char variable and vice-versa (convert a char into an 8-bit string). What is the best way to do this?
For example, if I want to store the 8-bit string 01010110 I could do like in this post [Convert from a binary to char in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10825218/convert-from-a-binary-to-char-in-c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    char *data = "01010110";
    char c = strtol(data, 0, 2);   
}
```

How can I do the opposite?